# Using __main__.py as entry point of Python module

Tags: python, import, entry-point

Consider I have a module call `app` and some user wants to import it on its script `caller.py`. The user has a local copy of the module `app` and his file structure is like this

```
parent_folder
├── caller.py
└── app
    ├── script_1.py
    ├── script_1.py
    └── __main__.py
```

`__main__.py` should be the entry point of `app` with some imports (pointing to `script_1` and `script_2` modules), classes and functions definitions.

```
# __main__.py
from app.script_1 import MyClassB
from app.script_2 import MyClassC


class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        print('This instanciate a MyClassA object')

def func_a():
    print('Some Function')
```

Consider `caller.py` the user's script that should be able to import `app` and use its classes and functions.

```
# caller.py
import app
app.func_a()
obj_a = app.MyClassA()
```

Running `python caller.py` on CMD (Windows 10 with Python 3.8.10) I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caller.py", line 2, in <module>
    app.func_a()
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'func_a'
```

I know that a modified version of `caller.py` will work

```
# caller.py
import app.__main__ as app
app.func_a()
obj_a = app.MyClassA()
```

With the desired output

```
Some Function
This instanciate a MyClassA object
```

However, `import app.__main__ as app` is far from ideal (not what is usually done when importing modules).

What is missing for me to use `__main__.py` as entry point of a module when importing from directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A package's `__main__.py` is what gets run if you try to execute the package with `python -m`. You're not running `python -m app`. You're running `python caller.py`. Your `__main__.py` never runs.

`__init__.py` is what gets run to initialize a package. You need an `__init__.py`, not a `__main__.py`.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112. I was confused by some information about `__init__.py` not being necessary for Python 3. But this answer led me to the right place. More can be learned on [Regular packages Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)